# Unable to load pinterest-linters (phabricator, arcanist)

Tags: lint, phabricator, arcanist

I was trying to add pinterest-linters to my project, but I got some errors when I `arc lint`.

```
 ARGV  '/Users/lushali/somewhere/arcanist/bin/../scripts/arcanist.php' 'lint' '--trace'
 LOAD  Loaded "phutil" from "/Users/lushali/somewhere/libphutil/src".
 LOAD  Loaded "arcanist" from "/Users/lushali/somewhere/arcanist/src".
Config: Reading user configuration file "/Users/lushali/.arcrc"...
Config: Did not find system configuration at "/etc/arcconfig".
Working Copy: Reading .arcconfig from "/Users/lushali/code/nexus_admin/.arcconfig".
Working Copy: Path "/Users/lushali/code/nexus_admin" is part of `git` working copy "/Users/lushali/code/nexus_admin".
Working Copy: Project root is at "/Users/lushali/code/nexus_admin".
Config: Did not find local configuration at "/Users/lushali/code/nexus_admin/.git/arc/config".
Loading phutil library from 'pinterest-linters'...
>>> [0] (+0) <exec> $ git rev-parse --verify HEAD^
<<< [0] (+10) <exec> 10,455 us
>>> [1] (+10) <exec> $ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name '@{upstream}'
<<< [1] (+20) <exec> 9,782 us
>>> [2] (+20) <exec> $ git cat-file -t 'origin/master'
<<< [2] (+34) <exec> 13,470 us
>>> [3] (+34) <exec> $ git merge-base 'origin/master' HEAD
<<< [3] (+46) <exec> 11,523 us
>>> [4] (+46) <exec> $ git diff --no-ext-diff --no-textconv --submodule=short --raw '1bba3081e23c945b3f795eedc73b99e3f509b5ed' HEAD --
<<< [4] (+59) <exec> 12,633 us
>>> [5] (+59) <exec> $ git --version
<<< [5] (+71) <exec> 11,867 us
>>> [6] (+71) <exec> $ git status --porcelain=2 -z
<<< [6] (+88) <exec> 16,486 us
>>> [7] (+88) <exec> $ git diff --no-ext-diff --no-textconv --submodule=short --no-color --src-prefix=a/ --dst-prefix=b/ -U32767 -M -C '1bba3081e23c945b3f795eedc73b99e3f509b5ed' --
<<< [7] (+120) <exec> 31,626 us
Examining paths for linter 'spelling'.
Found 6 matching paths for linter 'spelling'.
Examining paths for linter 'generated'.
Found 6 matching paths for linter 'generated'.
Examining paths for linter 'merge-conflict'.
Found 6 matching paths for linter 'merge-conflict'.
Examining paths for linter 'general-text'.
Found 4 matching paths for linter 'general-text'.
Examining paths for linter 'json'.
Found 4 matching paths for linter 'json'.

[2019-06-03 22:05:07] EXCEPTION: (PhutilProxyException) Error in parsing '.arclint' file, in key 'bin' for linter 'prettier-eslint'. {>} (Exception) None of the configured binaries can be located. at [<arcanist>/src/lint/linter/ArcanistExternalLinter.php:543]
arcanist(head=master, ref.master=7329bc7c32b9), phutil(head=master, ref.master=86ee6e90797c), pinterest-linters(head=master, ref.master=3628e14b6f57)
  #0 <#2> ArcanistExternalLinter::setLinterConfigurationValue(string, string) called at [<pinterest-linters>/src/PrettierESLintLinter.php:114]
  #1 <#2> PrettierESLintLinter::setLinterConfigurationValue(string, string) called at [<arcanist>/src/lint/engine/ArcanistConfigurationDrivenLintEngine.php:103]
  #2 ArcanistConfigurationDrivenLintEngine::buildLinters() called at [<arcanist>/src/lint/engine/ArcanistLintEngine.php:166]
  #3 ArcanistLintEngine::run() called at [<arcanist>/src/workflow/ArcanistLintWorkflow.php:337]
  #4 ArcanistLintWorkflow::run() called at [<arcanist>/scripts/arcanist.php:394]
```

I was following the instructions from the github (https://github.com/pinterest/arcanist-linters#global-installation)

Here is my `.arcconfig` file:

```
{
  "phabricator.uri" : "https://code.XXXXX.com/",
  "load": [
    "pinterest-linters"
  ]
}
```

I couldn't find `.bin/prettier-eslint` in my `node_modules` folder.  I think probably there is something wrong when Arcanist loaded the module.  I spent a lot of time searching online, but I got nothing useful.  Can someone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, which one of the ways did you follow? Global or project installation. Is the `pinterest-linters` repo the same directory as of `arcanist` and `libphutil`?

Comment: @Pouyan Thanks so much for replying me.  Global Installation.  Yes, they are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, I think you need to create an `.arclint` file on top of adding `pinterest-linters` to your `.arcconfig` file. For example, an `.arclint` file for `prettier` and `eslint` would look something like this:

```
{
  "linters": {
    "eslint": {
      "type": "eslint",
      "include": ["(\\.js$)", "(\\.jsx$)"],
      "bin": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint",
      "eslint.config": ".eslintrc",
      "eslint.env": "browser,node"
    },
    "prettier": {
      "type": "prettier",
      "include": ["(\\.js$)", "(\\.jsx$)"],
      "bin": "./node_modules/.bin/prettier",
      "prettier.cwd": "./"
    }
  }
}
```

However, yours may be different as your error message states that you use `prettier-eslint`.